# Null Hypothesis and Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Question: I desire to test the null hypothesis that the 90th percentile of some population is 3, against the alternative hypothesis that it is greater than 3. I will base my test on the number of values that are bigger than 3 in a random sample of size 5 with replacement from the population. Assume that if the 90th percentile really is 3, the number of values bigger than 3 is like the number of tickets labeled "1" one gets in five random draws with replacement from a box that contains 9 tickets labeled "0" and one ticket labeled "1." To have a test with significance level 1%, what is the number of sample values greater than 3 I should reject the null hypothesis?

I suppose the expected number of sample values greater than three is 0.5, given if the null hypothesis be true, the number of values greater than three has a binomial distribution with parameters n = 5 and p = 1/9. I know the correct answer is greater than two but I'm not sure how to approach it by calculation.

Comment: Why do you have $p=1/9$ and not $p=1/10$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $90$th percentile is greater than three than more than $10\%$ of the population is greater than three so it might be clearer if you restated

- your null hypothesis as something like "$10\%$ of the population is greater than three"
- your alternative hypothesis like "more than $10\%$ of the population is greater than three"

This means that an extreme result is a large number of your sample sized $5$ with replacement being greater than three.  You can find the probabilities and the cumulative probabilities using the binomial distribution with $n=5$ and $p=0.10$ to get something like

```
>three  prob   cumulative

  5    0.00001 0.00001
  4    0.00045 0.00046
  3    0.00810 0.00856
  2    0.07290 0.08146
  1    0.32805 0.40951
  0    0.59049 1.00000
```

So there is a probability under the null hypothesis of about $0.00856 \lt 0.01$ that you see $3$ or more of your sample values greater than three, but about $0.08146 \gt 0.01$ that you see $2$ or more of your sample values greater than three. So at a $1\%$ level of significance, seeing $3$ or more of your sample values greater than three would lead you to reject the null hypothesis.